# Mvel with many expressions

Tags: java, mvel

I thought of using Mvel to evaluate dynamic expressions.
These expressions are customer specific. For some of the customers they may be in hundreds.
To evaluate these it is increasing the time based on the number of expressions.
Is there any way I can optimize to reduce the time.

I tried to use evaluateAllExpressions after compilation. But still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Better you implement multithreading and execute each expression in a separate thread.
Use Futures/callables.

We are also doing the same thing, we also have any number of business rules that have to be fired.